# How to pass quotation marks to javascript function

Tags: javascript, input

I have a javascript function which accepts strings which include quotation marks and displays in a input field. But this function does not accept the string after the quotation mark

```
function searchFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    return '<input id="txt' + cellvalue + '" type="text"  disabled="disabled"  value="' + cellvalue + '" />';
}
```

**Eg. 21" Inch ==> 21**

Is there anyway I can pass quotation marks to the function and print them. I don't want to **replace** them. I want to **display** them.

Comment: where would this 21" go to, value of cellValue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must escape special HTML characters like `"`, `<`, `>`.
Eg:

```
function searchFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    cellvalue = cellvalue.
                replace(/&/g,'&amp;').
                replace(/>/g,'&gt;').
                replace(/</g,'&lt;').
                replace(/"/g,'&quot;');
    return '<input id="txt' + cellvalue + '" type="text"  disabled="disabled"  value="' + cellvalue + '" />';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the value of the cellValue as shown below
(
var cellValue = 21"(Should be given as 21 followed by &quot followed by ;(semicolon))

You can get the value as **21"** in the input box.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace " with &quot;

Use this helper method:

```
function htmlEncodeInputDisplay(string) {
    if (string == null || jQuery.trim(string) == "") return string;
    string = string.replace(/&lt;/g, "<");
    string = string.replace(/&gt;/g, ">");
    string = string.replace(/&amp;/g, "&");
    string = string.replace(/&nbsp;/g, " ");
    string = string.replace(/\"/g, "&quot;");
    return string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Javascript Functions **escape()** to encode a sting and then unescape() to decode them if needed.

You can also manually escape them like in the example below.

```
var name = prompt("Please write your \'name\' in the box\r Write it with \"quotes\" like this.","");
```

The quote escaped using \ goes through as a part of the string.

Comment: could you also explain why you think so? :)  He just wants to display them in a input field where this escaping should work just fine.

Comment: Have you tried what you have suggested with the input box? If so you would not have asked this question to me.

Comment: Well still not sure why you dont answer! but if you need to .. yes i have tried escape().. and it does work! Check Hoff's answer if you need the details!

Comment: Did you check with the " 21\" " it wont work for sure. Oh you removed it now ah? Great

Comment: I did to avoid confusion so people can concentrate on getting their answers right than commenting! :P and just in case you aint used to reading the whole answers, my first suggestion is using escape(). Then i go ahead and mention other options.

Answer (score 0):

just escape the value when creating the input element, and then unescape the value to display it correctly.

Simplified example:

```
function make_input(val) {
    return '<input value="' + escape(val) + '" />';
}

// add to dom

$('input').each(function(){
   var current_value = $(this).val()
   var new_value = unescape(current_value)
   $(this).val(new_value)
})
```