# How to code a formula that will call a variable string that may contain quotation marks?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm sorry, I know the issue was addressed before, but I can't make any answer fit my problem...

I am writing a short script on google script, where I want to use the searchFile method on a folder, to look for a file whose name is stored in the string variable Name:

```
var theFileImLookingFor = theSourceFolder.searchFiles("title = '"+Name+"'").next();
```

This code works fine as long as the variable Name doesn't include quotation marks. Then, I'm stuck...

Please help me adapt my code :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass quotation marks to javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655342/how-to-pass-quotation-marks-to-javascript-function)

Answer (score 0):

A simple but fragile solution could be to use backticks (`), usually found on the upper left of the keyboard on the same key as the tilde (~). These are sort of like quotation marks in javascript, but can also be used in ways that quotation marks can't.

Expect this solution to fail whenever the variable's value contains backticks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to escape possible quotes ?
You probably could write a little function that take your variable "name" then escape possible quotes in it before returning it to searchFile. Or maybe with a simple "replace("'", "\'")"...